# Android imageview.setBackground

Tags: android

Relative code snippet:

```
 imageviewkapak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(imageviewkapak.getDrawable()!=null){;
                    Bitmap b =antiblur(karsicover, 20f);
                    Drawable c = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);
                    imageviewkapak.setBackground(c);
                    Log.i("tago" , "bos atma");
                }


public Bitmap antiblur(Bitmap image , float radius){
    final float BLUR_RADIUS = radius;
            if (null == image) return null;
            Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
            final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(getActivity());
            Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
            Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
            //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
            ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
            theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
            theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
            theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
            tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
            return outputBitmap;
```

I want to change image with blurred version when user clicks on "imageviewkapak". But it doesn't change. What is my mistake ?

Comment: You tried replacing `imageviewkapak.setBackground(c);` with `imageviewkapak.setImageDrawable(c);`? Or are you specifically trying to change the background of the imageview and not the view's _actual_ image?

Comment: I try to change specifically the background of the imageview

Comment: May a little bit off the topic, but if you are trying to do call blur several times, it is better to create and cache RenderScript and ScriptIntrinsicBlur objects. Creating them for every blur will hurt the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to blur your bitmap first:

```
public Bitmap blurBitMapImage(Context context,Bitmap mbitmap, int radius) {
    try {
        int numPixels = mbitmap.getWidth() * mbitmap.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[numPixels];
        mbitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, mbitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, mbitmap.getWidth(), mbitmap.getHeight());
        mbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mbitmap.getWidth(), mbitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mbitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, mbitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, mbitmap.getWidth(), mbitmap.getHeight());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(context);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            mbitmap.getWidth(), mbitmap.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, mbitmap);
    Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript,
            Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    blur.setInput(blurInput);
    blur.setRadius(radius); 
    blur.forEach(blurOutput);

    blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);
    renderScript.destroy();

    return bitmap;
}
```

And then you can set the blurred bitmap in this way :

```
imageviewkapak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick (View v){
        if (imageviewkapak.getDrawable() != null) {
            blurredImageView.setImageBitmap(blurBitMapImage(this,karsicover, 20));
            Log.i("tago", "bos atma");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setBackground(), which literally sets the background of the image only and doesn't change the foreground image. Try using

```
setImageDrawable(<your_drawable>);
```

In case you actually are trying to set the background of the image, you will need to add margins to your imageview so that the background is visible without getting covered by the foreground image. Try using LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
imageviewkapak.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This creates a margin of 5 pixels around your imageview, allowing the background to be visible.